# UISegmentedControl with custom prev/next buttons

Tags: iphone, fonts, icons, uisegmentedcontrol, uinavigationitem

I am trying to reach the following result

[here](http://blog.episode-2.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/uisegmentedcontrol-1.jpg)

I know how to configure the segmented control but I was wondering how to get the same icons ... I tried to do it with photoshop but I just can't manage to achieve the same quality !

I heard there is a possibility to use the "Apple symbols font" available on Mac (which contains these icons), could you show me how to get these symbols ?

Or if you have a link to these precise icons (for free) It would be nice too.

Thank you,

ChaCha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [NavBar](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/NavBar/index.html)  [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+Code) in the [apple developers](http://developer.apple.com/) page contains these two images and shows you how to implement them.